# boost::asio crash when using a member acceptor instead of new one

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to put the acceptor, socket and endpoint as members into my class but ran into crashes. Must the socket be a shared_ptr like in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501167/declaring-a-boost-asio-socket-acceptor-and-endpoint-in-a-class-headerfile) or why does it not work?

When I'm trying to setup a acceptor on a server like this:

```
tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(localIpAddress), portNumber);
tcp::acceptor a(io_service);
tcp::socket s(io_service);
a.open(ep.protocol());
a.bind(ep);
a.listen(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
a.async_accept(s, boost::bind(&WifiConnector::onAccept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

it runs without crashing during execution, but when I try to use a socket/acceptor/endpoint that are member of my WifiConnector class it crashes.

```
m_acceptor.open(localEndpoint.protocol()); // it crashes in this line already
m_acceptor.bind(localEndpoint);
m_acceptor.listen(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
m_acceptor.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(&WifiConnector::onAccept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

declaration in WifiConnector.hpp:

```
private:
    tcp::socket m_socket;
    tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    tcp::endpoint m_localEndpoint;
```

initialization at class constructor:

```
WifiConnector::WifiConnector() :
    io_service(),
    m_socket(io_service),
    m_acceptor(io_service)
{
    m_localIpAddress    = "192.168.137.1";
    m_portNumber        = 30000;
    m_localEndpoint = tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(m_localIpAddress), m_portNumber);
}
```

when it crashes, I get the following exeption:

```
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >
```

Comment: Given that the problem arises when you refactor the code into a class, I think you really need to provide a [mcve].  Failing that, can you at least show the declaration of `WifiConnector::io_service`?

Answer (score -1):

```
private:
    tcp::socket m_socket;
    tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    tcp::endpoint m_localEndpoint;
```

This will not work.  You are constructing using the default constructors, which is not what you want.  For one thing you want to construct using the io_service used by everything else.

Make the attributes pointers, and construct them using new when you have the io_service.

Comment: The default constructor is not used (it is not possible b/c there is none for socket etc,) but the right constructors are called (including the io_service) when the WifiConnector constructor is called see "initialization at class constructor"